# What settings to use on video rendering from image sequence?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, file-format, resolution

So I exported my image sequence as 4k res png files from Eevee, 270 frames, and now I need to create a video from it. I couldn't find any reasonable information explaining everything about the process so here's my noob questions:

Do I need the same render settings when rendering the video as the render settings when rendering the image sequences ? Does sample count even matter when I already exported the images as 90 samples, should I put the same samples when rendering the video ?

My images are 4k resolution, should I put 4k resolution in the output of the video render as well ?

Do these settings even matter when I already have the images ? And if not, which settings matter when rendering the video ? Should I render the video from the same scene file or should I load a new one ?

I tried rendering my images as a video but the video is all jagged with all sorts of artifacts and the video is on a small screen resolution even though I put 4k resolution ?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can answer my questions !

Answer (score 1):

1. Not necessarily. You would need to change the filetype to mp4 or any other video format though.
2. I just checked and the sample count doesn't seem to matter for rendering from VSE.
3. Yes, the resolution matters.
4. No, it doesn't matter. You can render all the pngs and compile them to a video in another blend file.
5. I don't know the exact issue but you should check the color management of the scenes. I think Filmic is enabled by default for rendering which is not what you might want. Also, rendering from VSE takes a lot of time and it is not very flexible. If you want to do some heavy editing, I would suggest other programs specifically designed for this purpose, like Premiere or DaVinci Resolve (which is free).

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! The color management seems to mess up with the end result a lot. High contrast for example gets applied on both when rendering my images and when rendering from VSE. I played around but nothing seem to work, my video is still jagged and too dark. I will give DaVinci Resolve a try, thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Wait wait wait... Are you rendering a 3D scene with Cycles/eevee or have you already rendered your 3D scene into an image sequence and just want to have those pictures turned into a video file ? In the second case, you are not doing any 3D rendering, so 3D render settings don't matter.